# How does the Roslyn C# compiler know where to find .NET assembly files?

Tags: .net, roslyn, csc

I've downloaded a copy of Roslyn using `nuget.exe` into a empty directory on my computer. I've then created a few small test files in C# to play with the compiler. In my code, I'm using features from the .NET Framework such as `SqlDataReader`. When compiling with the `csc.exe` binary included with Roslyn, I do not manually specify any .NET assemblies to be included with the `-reference` or `-r` command line options, but everything still works.

I have found the `csc.rsp` file in the same directory as `csc.exe` including some of these .NET assemblies. Command line options in this file are automatically added if the `-noconfig` command line option is not specified. Part of the file looks like this:

```
# Reference the common Framework libraries
/r:Accessibility.dll
/r:Microsoft.CSharp.dll
/r:System.Configuration.dll
/r:System.Configuration.Install.dll
/r:System.Core.dll
/r:System.Data.dll
/r:System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
/r:System.Data.Linq.dll
/r:System.Data.OracleClient.dll
/r:System.Deployment.dll
```

I suspect that this `csc.rsp` file is the reason the compiler can successfully compile my code even though I haven't manually included any .NET assemblies. My question, though, is how `csc.exe` even knows where to look for these files?

I searched the entire Roslyn directory with VSCode for any possible configuration specifying which paths to search for assemblies but nothing jumped out at me. I also checked my system path variable for directory that it may be automatically getting the files from but I couldn't find anything there either. How does `csc.exe` include these files even though I haven't told the it where to look for them on my computer?

Answer (score 3):

> How does csc.exe include these files even though I haven't told the it where to look for them on my computer?

It runs code that looks for the files where it expects them to be.  The default location of the .NET framework code is discoverable by the compiler. If you want to know the exact details, read the source code of the compiler.

The class you want to look at is anything that derives from MetadataReferenceResolver. See

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/search?q=MetadataReferenceResolver

For the command line compiler you'll specifically want to look at `LoggingMetadataFileReferenceResolver`, which delegates most of its work to a `RelativePathResolver`.

Comment: Can I manually tell the compiler where to look for the assemblies?

Comment: @AaronBeaudoin: Yes. If that was your question, **that's the question you should have asked**. Try to ask the question you actually want an answer to; that saves the person trying to answer your question from wasting time.

Comment: That was not at all my original question, but after reading your response I would consider it logical follow up, wouldn't you? Should I create a new question?

Comment: @AaronBeaudoin: No.  **You should always do basic research before you ask any question on StackOverflow**.  If you want to know how to tell the compiler where to look for assemblies, **read the compiler documentation**.  Start with `csc /?` and read all the options to the compiler. Or, if you're using Visual Studio, look at the project properties pane.

Answer (score -1):

Those assemblies are in the [Global Assembly Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/gac).